# Retire [golfing-language]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[golfing-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golfing-language) has **<s>7</s> 5 questions and 0 followers**.

From its wiki, it is:

> For questions regarding languages for golfing.
>
> This tag is for
> questions regarding choice of programming language for golfing. It can
> be used for help with creation of a new language, or for tips
> regarding choice of language, or for anything else regarding golfing
> languages.

**This is *not* on topic on the main site.**

Of its <s>7</s> 5 questions:

- **all 5** are closed / on hold
- **all 5** have at least one other tag, and [golfing-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golfing-language) is completely superfluous

This tag doesn't seem to hold any value, and actively harms the quality of the site by encouraging off-topic questions.

What should be done with it? If you can't tell, I think it should be burninated.

Comment: Why bother, when we didn't even retire the tag [tag:1p5]? It has "encouraged" off-topic question at least once, which I wasn't sure why the OP thought it's a good idea using it. I really don't think those tags can encourage anything, as most users aren't even aware of their existence. But the question askers thought they are relevant after writing the question.

Comment: @jimmy23013 1p5 seems to be on topic, like a tag about project euler

Comment: So do you think the remaining two questions not closed are also off-topic?

Comment: @jimmy23013 I don't follow what relevance 1p5 has, but yes, I noted in the second bullet (as did Mego's answer) they're not good, on topic questions

Comment: @jimmy23013 I didn't even know we had a 1p5 tag. Might post a burninate request for that later. Seems like a useless meta tag to me.

Comment: @MartinBüttner [status-completed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8644/46231)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Yes, let's retire it

Why?

- It encourages off-topic questions (*How do I use X golfing language?*, *Which of X, Y, Z golfing languages should I use?*, *How does feature Y work in X golfing language?*).
- We never use it.
- Its presence supports the stratification of languages into "golfing" and "non-golfing", which is unfair to both sides (any language can be used, keeping in mind our usual caveats, and segregating the languages designed for code golf perpetuates the discrimination against them).