# Historical lock for "Language idea for golfing purposes"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Language idea for golfing purposes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6977/46231) is a very interesting question with very interesting answers.

While retagging the two non-closed questions tagged [golfing-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golfing-language) per [Retire [golfing-language]?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8617/retire-golfing-language), I found this question. It opens with:

> This question is probably not on-topic. If a moderator feels that it should be that way, turn this question into community wiki please.

It was made CW just 7 hours after it was posted, which seems to support my theory that it's not on topic within the scope defined in the [help center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you feel it is, kindly DV this post and leave a comment describing your opinion.

---

<s>Assuming the previous is accepted as true,</s> The question was put on hold as a result.

I (still) think this is a valuable question which may be helpful to future visitors / users, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so [people should] not use it as evidence that [they] can ask similar questions here.**

Does that sound like a piece of text we all know well? <sup>yes</sup>

---

If this question is worthy of closure as off-topic (hint: it is), then I would like to propose it be locked as well, to prevent reopening, possible deletion, and because it is important and shouldn't be thrown away with the other closed questions.

Comment: It's definitely off topic per [the meta consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1727/20469), but I don't think it's actually notable enough warrant a historical lock.

Comment: @AlexA. you've gotta cute lil mod badge, why not make that an answer and this [tag:status-declined]? :P

Comment: Well, since this is a [discussion], not a [feature-request], there isn't really anything to decline. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is off topic per [the meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1727/20469) and isn't notable enough to warrant a historical lock. The moderators discussed the best course of action and decided to simply delete the question.