# Let's deliberate about [1p5]

Tags: discussion, tags, challenges

Back in April 2011, [@dmkcee](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78/dmckee) announced [the CodeGolf.SE First Periodic Premier Programming Puzzle Push](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/46231). This proposal was *so* promising and interesting that [even Jeff Atwood took note](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298/announcing-the-codegolf-se-first-periodic-premier-programming-puzzle-push#comment640_298)!

The [1p5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1p5) tag was introduced to classify this new venture of code challenges, as a bit of a meta-tag. Today, this tag has a meager **four questions** and **0 followers**.

These four questions are not just random low-quality posts, however. They have accrued:

- a **total of 111 votes**, for an **average of 27.5 votes each** (13, 19, 33, 46)
- a **total of 9.5k views**, for an **average of ~2.4k views each** (580, 1k, 4k, 4k)
- a **total of 47 high-quality answers** for an **average of 12 answers each** (5, 3, 19, 20)
- a **total of 24 stars** for an **average of 6 stars each** (4, 0, 12, 8)

The tag's first two questions were posted in quick sucession shortly after [@dmkcee](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78/dmckee) announced 1P5, and they were the most well-recieved. The most recent two questions were asked just a week later, and received far less of the the gold dust enjoyed by the originals.

---

Yesterday, I [wrote](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8617) a proposal here on meta to burninate [golfing-language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golfing-language), to which [@jimmy23013](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/25180/jimmy23013) [commented](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8617/retire-golfing-language#comment24474_8617):

> [...] we didn't even retire the tag 1p5. It has "encouraged" off-topic questions at least once. [...]

My assumption is he's referring to questions posted under that tag which were deleted / closed / untagged.

---

**TL;DR** At the time, 1P5 was a *very* effective effort on the part of [@dmkcee](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78/dmckee) and the community at large to improve site participation and quality, but...

...skip forward 5 years to today: PPCG has graduated, and we're looking like a very successful site (98% answered, loads of awesome questions per day, etc), so *we no longer need 1P5 because it helped us grow.* However, **what should happen to the tag and its questions?** It's both a meta-tag and nearly pointless from the tiny number of ancient questions with it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Retire it but leave it be

As it stands, only 4 challenges bear that tag. It wouldn't be a huge endeavor to retag them. However, the [1p5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1p5) tag itself obviously has notable historical significance for our site. Thus I think we should keep the tag around to mark the challenges that were part of this effort, but retire its use for new challenges.

In general, I think tags like this are unnecessary; they group together challenges that are otherwise entirely unrelated, which contradicts the purpose of tags in my mind. But even now that we're all grown up, we should acknowledge our humble beginnings and the efforts of those who got us where we are today.

Comment: I've added a bit to the tag wiki at the end: *Do not use this tag for new questions.* Just in case the preceding part wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @IGoBest Sounds perfect. Thanks!